# How to create custom Widget programmatically that will allow me to show the newest Products in Home Page?

Tags: magento2, widget

I want to create a Custom widget through codes that will allow me to display the newest products on the home page where my widget will get inserted.

Comment: you can create from backend **content -> pages** or do you want to create a programmatically?

Comment: programmatically